# Flaw in my logic on Henry's Law?

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, solutions, gas-laws

It states mathematically $ p=Kx $ where $x$ is mole fraction of dissolved gas and $p$ is partial pressure of the gas.
Dissolution of gases is exothermic, so with increase in temperature, solubility $x$ decreases.
But increase in temperature also means an increase in partial pressure $p$ which in turn means an increase in solubility $x$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Temperature only affects pressure if you allow it to: by keeping volume constant. If your system has a freely moving piston holding the gas for example, then temperature will lead to a volume expansion, pressure remaining constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Henry's law is](http://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law.html):

> **At a constant temperature**, the amount of a given gas dissolved in a given type and volume of liquid is directly proportional to the partial pressure of that gas in equilibrium with that liquid.

If temperature changes, the Henry's law constant itself changes.

Comment: But how does it change? As in what is the dependence of K and temperature?

Comment: @Cowgirl read the section "Temperature dependence of Henry's law constant" in the linked webpage

Comment: Read also: !https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1387380615002183.